# KL divergence and sign

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-model, variational-autoencoder

In the [Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114) paper, the formula for KL divergence is
$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum \bigl (1 + \log(σ^2) - μ^2 - σ^2 \bigr) \space\space\space\space...(10)$$
, but the equation is
$$- D_{KL}(q(z|x)||p(z)) \space\space\space\space...(7)$$
with a minus sign. why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is this Pytorch expression equivalent to the KL divergence?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/how-is-this-pytorch-expression-equivalent-to-the-kl-divergence) In particular, see my answer there ;)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition as you can see, there is a very simple way to get rid of the minus

Comment: I see. I understood. thank you.